# CsvHelper not Validating if Conversion is set

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

Using the CsvHelper library, the validation does not trigger if the Map has a Convert defined.

Example:

```
Map(m => m.ProjectStock)
                .Validate(x =>
                    csvMapHelper.TrueStringsList.Contains(x.Field) || csvMapHelper.FalseStringList.Contains(x.Field))
                .Convert(args =>
                {
                    var projectStock = args.Row.GetField("ProjectStock");
                    return csvMapHelper.TrueStringsList.Contains(projectStock);
                });
```

If I run this code, only the Convert fires, but the Validate is skipped.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why the `Validate` method does not fire. However, I believe there is an easier way to do what you are trying to do.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name,ProjectStock\n1,Jordan,tak\n2,Beth,no"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanTrueValues.AddRange(CsvMapHelper.TrueStringsList);
        csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.GetOptions<bool>().BooleanFalseValues.AddRange(CsvMapHelper.FalseStringList);
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }   
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ProjectStock { get; set; }
}

public class CsvMapHelper
{
    public static List<string> TrueStringsList => new List<string> { "yes", "true", "tak" };
    public static List<string> FalseStringList => new List<string> { "no", "false", "nie" };    
}
```